# memoir: Stop margins from getting wider with fontsize

Tags: margins, memoir, geometry

When I increase the fontsize of my document from 10pt through 12pt and 14pt, the margins of the document (I'm using `memoir`) increase as well. Is it possible to use a command that keeps the margins fixed, or do I have to adjust manually myself?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, the margins stay at what they were in `10pt` size.

Note though, that the sectioning sizes did not change.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\fontsize{14pt}{17pt}\selectfont

\chapter{One}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

[image]

For comparison, here is the raw `10pt` result:

[image]

To get the 14pt carried through into section headings, etc., as David points out, requires one to set the `[14pt]` document class option.  In order to use that and *approximately* preserve the `[10pt]` margins, one can attempt to recreate it with `margin` parameters to the `geometry` package:

```
\documentclass[14pt,letterpaper]{memoir}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=2.275in,top=1.7in,bottom=1.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{layout}
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @StevenBSegletes This is nice, thanks. Which number denotes the fontsize in `\fontsize{14pt}{17pt}\selectfont`, 14 or 17? And what does the other number do?

Comment: @BillyJean The `14pt` is the fontsize, the `17pt` is the baselineskip (aka line spacing).

Comment: How does one make the sectioning sizes change accordingly?

Comment: @BillyJean `\fontsize` just changes the font at that point, to change all settings in a consistent way use the documentclass option

Comment: @BillyJean See the follow-up I added to my answer.